# Subqueries and Aggregation - SQL

Tags: sql

1. Find the total units sold at each event, total units per product sold at each event, and event duration in days.
2. Use one SQL statement to complete this

https://i.stack.imgur.com/h94dp.jpg

Here's what I have so far, it's just the bare minimum. I think that there is some sort of subquery(ies) involved, but i'm not sure.

**1. Selecting total units at each event:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(units), count(*)
from (JOIN TABLE i and TABLE e on Event_ID --> I know how to do this, just shortening the code)
GROUP BY event_id
```

**

**2. Total Units Per Product Sold At Each Event

```
SELECT COUNT(UNITS)/COUNT(PROUDCT) AS 'Units Per Product Sold'
FROM inventory
GROUP BY event_id**
```

My main issue is combining the clauses together and implementing the subquery (if it is actually needed) and the exact phrasing of the second select statement

Comment: Please share insert statement to re-generate the situation.

Comment: Which dbms you are using? And mention your desired output.

Comment: `distinct` is **not** a function. It always applies to all columns in the select list. Enclosing one of the columns with parentheses won't change anything and is useless. `distinct (a),b` is the same as `distinct a,(b)` or `distinct a,b`

Comment: Note that your GROUP BY usage in the first query is invalid standard SQL and will be rejected by every self-respecting DBMS - which DBMS product are you using

Answer (score 0):

You can use windows function to achieve those:

**Schema**

```
create table event(event_id int ,event_name varchar(20),event_start_date date,event_end_date date);
insert into event values(1,'a','2021/03/05','2021/03/06');

create table event_inventory_table(event_id int, product_id int,units int);
insert into event_inventory_table values(1,1,10);
insert into event_inventory_table values(1,5,5);
```

**Query #1 (SQL Server)**

```
select e.event_id,e.event_name,datediff(day,e.event_start_date,e.event_end_date)evnt_Duration,product_id,sum(units)over(partition by e.event_id) Units_Sold,sum(units)over(partition by e.event_id,product_id) units_sold_per_product from event e
```

left join event_inventory_table eit on e.event_id=eit.event_id

**Query #2 (MySQL 8.0)**

select e.event_id,e.event_name,datediff(e.event_end_date,e.event_start_date)evnt_Duration,product_id,sum(units)over(partition by e.event_id) Units_Sold,sum(units)over(partition by e.event_id,product_id) units_sold_per_product from event e
left join event_inventory_table eit on e.event_id=eit.event_id

**Output:**

| event_id | event_name | evnt_Duration | Units_Sold | units_sold_per_product | product_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 1 | 15 | 10 | 1 |
| 1 | a | 1 | 15 | 5 | 5 |